# Is it (still) possible to play/stream files from a controlling remote Android device to Kodi?

Tags: remote, streaming, xbmc

I am used to Kodi media centre. I hold the recollection it was possible to play local media files from a controlling Android device, installed with Yatse at least, i.e. Yatse would manage to stream audio/video files to Kodi through the network provided both Kodi and the Android device are connected to the same network. If my memory serves me right it was the concept of "Play local files", right?

I can't seem to find back the option on Yatse *nor can I find any hint on the Internet any more*. Instead I find countless links to play/stream *from* Kodi *to* Chromecast and so on. Not what I want.

Did I dream it or has the option disappeared? Is it possible anyway to have audio and video files on a remote Android device played with Kodi through the network? If the answer is "yes", how would I do that?

Comment: There's Kodi for android now, which you can use as a controlling/server device like any other instance of Kodi.

Comment: The android device I was referring to is supposed to be a remote for Kodi because the device which Kodi runs on has no input peripherals (no keyboard, no mouse). Running another instance of Kodi somewhere else might confuse the user, right? Or am I completely mistaken?

Comment: Use Kodi on the phone to play on Kodi on the big screen. Makes it simple for me. ;p

Comment: Sorry, I've just tried it on my phone and it' a big no-no. I've struggled to figure out how to use it to control another Kodi instance, to no avail. Just exiting the application took me minutes as the power button just didn't respond... It has serious usability issues (maybe limited to my phone, I don't know) and doesn't address my requirement so I'm sorry it's not what I'm looking for. Maybe I'm just missing something but I'm at a loss here. Is there a guide?

Answer (score 0):

Kodi speaks DLNA, so any device/program/app that can stream over DLNA can be used to stream to Kodi on any device it's installed on.

Comment: Well, this partly answers my question but I know none of these, do do you have some hints?

Comment: There's Kodi, and BubblePnP (paid). Beyond that, do a search for DLNA in the android Play Store.